# Show checkbox values in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, checkbox

I am looking for a way to show a result string with the checkbox values selected in a form.
I couldnt find a a way to do it.

To clarify:

[ ] Apples

[X] Lemons

[ ] Oranges

[X] Limes

Selected : Lemons, Limes

---

My checkbox has the following syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{fruit}}" ng-model="value1" ng-bind="fruit"/>
```

Im getting the list of values from a JSON file.

Does anybody know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try.
Use the ngChange directive to bind a callback :

In your controller, update a list of selected fruits and display your message :

```
  $scope.selectedFruits = [];
  $scope.message = "";

  function renderMessage(){
     $scope. message ='';
    for (var i = 0; i <  $scope.selectedFruits.length; i++)
      $scope. message +=  $scope.message ? ", "+$scope.selectedFruits[i] : $scope.selectedFruits[i];
       $scope.message = "Selected : "+ $scope.message
   return $scope.message;
  }; 

  $scope.updateFruits = function(name) {
   var alreadyExisting = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedFruits.length; i++) {
      if (name === $scope.selectedFruits[i])
      {
         $scope.selectedFruits.splice(i, 1);
         alreadyExisting = true;
      }
     }
   if (!alreadyExisting)
     $scope.selectedFruits.push(name);
   renderMessage();
  };
```

EDIT : I was in a hurry at noon and I couldn't provide you a functionnal version. I updated my code and created a plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/3YOAzV